# Can you replace glucose with glycerol in cell media?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, cell-culture, respiration

In order to feed an **animal cell** in process called **Respiration**, can I replace Glucose with Glycerol?

*The Equation bellow:
Glycerol + Oxygen -> Water + Carbon Oxide*

Comment: Experiments have already been carried out regarding the utilization of glycerol by yeast cells. Maybe this is what you were asking? 
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1968.tb00353.x/pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, it's not a good idea to replace glucose with glycerol in animal cell media. Animals do possess the ability to metabolize glycerol, via a pathway starting with the enzyme glycerol kinase. However, glycerol kinase is only expressed in certain cell types, such as liver cells and kidney cells.

References:

http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=2.7.1.30
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22591/